# Converegence of $x_n = (\sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} -n)(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{2n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

Let $x_n =  (\sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} -n)(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{2n})$ for each $n\geq 1$. I am looking for easy ways to show that $(x_n)$ is convergent. I have tried to show that is decreasing and bounded, but I got stucked. Also, I tried to find a formula $x_n =f(x_{n-1})$ but I failed. Besides, by using a computer, I can tell that it is convergent with limit $\lim x_n = (1+\sqrt{2})/2\approx 1.207106781$. Clearly, this is a root of $4x^2-4x-1$, maybe this suggest a way of solve this problem, but I can't relate the sequence with that second order polynomial.

What it is the best way to attack this problem of convergence of sequence? Are there any  'algebra trick' that make the problem easier? and, once  the convergence is proved, how can I calculate $\lim x_n$ without the help of a computer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank for all your answer. The first thing i tried was multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{2n}$, which does not work. Clearly, the idea was the correct but with the other factor... Can't say how I got stucked in such an easy exercise... anyway, thank you once more, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

Use formula $$\boxed{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = {a-b \over \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}}$$

\begin{align}x_n &= \color{red}{(\sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} -n)}(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{2n})\\
&= \color{red}{{n^2 + \sqrt{n} -n^2\over \sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} +n }}\cdot \sqrt{n}\Big( \sqrt{1+{1\over n}} + \sqrt{2}\Big)\\
&= { n\over n\cdot (\sqrt{1+ {\sqrt{n}\over n^2}} +1) }\cdot \Big( \sqrt{1+{1\over n}} + \sqrt{2}\Big)\\
&\to {1+\sqrt{2}\over 2} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} -n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} +n}$$

and then

$$x_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{2n})}{\sqrt{n^2 + \sqrt{n}} +n}$$

which can be easily solved factoring out $n$ from numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right: $$x_n=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt2}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}}}\rightarrow\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2}$$